# Remove Excess Space in Gridview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gridview

[Current Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnRFa.jpg)

I want the 3rd image to take up the white space. The gridview looks good when the height of the images are equal but when its unequal it shows blank to match up with the next images height. i just want the below image to come up and fill up the space.

Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
int logos[];
LayoutInflater inflter;
public Adapter(Context applicationContext, int[] logos) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.logos = logos;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return logos.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, null); // inflate the layout
    ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.icon); // get the reference of ImageView
    icon.setImageResource(logos[i]); // set logo images
    return view;
}
```

}

Custom View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="1dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
        GridView mGridView = findViewById(R.id.grid); 
    Adapter customAdapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), logos);
    mGridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Usually use recycler view but needed columns so switched to gridview. I found sources on making the images equal height. But i dont want that. I dont want it to keep aspect ratio but just fill up all the available space

Comment: set height of imageview to 50 or 100dp

Comment: @PrajwalW i want the height to be adjusted according to the height of the picture instead of setting a height for all pictures

Comment: If that is the case they the output u r getting for your code is correct as per your req....

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="1dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work man. And i dont think weight without weightsum is useful. not sure though. any other solutions?